# What are the differences between social anxiety and panic attacks in terms of symptoms?

Tags: mental-health, symptoms, terminology, panic-attack, social-anxiety

**What are the differences between social anxiety and panic attacks in terms of symptoms?**

Does social anxiety lead to panic attacks?